категория состояния
На одном из лингвистических сайтов написано, что слова категории состояния образуют группы слов. Одной из групп были краткие страдательные причастия (накурено, обнаружено, указано).
Не совсем поняла такую формулировку, т. к. даже если брать безличное предложение с причастиями, то оно и будет причастием, никак не словом категории состояния.
Категория состояния в русском языке
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/kategoriia-sostoianiia.html#i-3

Там, в источнике, не было группы "кратких страдательных причастий". Там были "слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода".

возникает вопрос, что тогда это значит? краткие страдательные причастия мы не можем назвать категорией состояния‍♀️‍♀️

Думаю, "существо накурено" — это причастие, говорящее о действии (а не состоянии), совершённом персонажем. "В комнате накурено"  — это уже наречие, категория состояния, здесь акцент не на действии. Грань тонка и спорна. Реально отстоять любое мнение по таким вопросам.

В грамматике нет своих мнений. Правильно то, что правильным считают лингвисты, а задача пользователей — это понять обоснованность предлагаемых решений.

Ага, про авторскую пунктуацию, значимость контекста, нерешённые вопросы русского языка и т.д., Шарон, конечно, предпочитает "забыть" и связать до сих пор развивающийся живой язык абстракциями учебников. Между тем, умные люди давно высказались иначе: https://clck.ru/3F4Koq

Это пока не ответ, а просто информация.

Полагаю, что вопрос закономерен. Слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода, отнесены к словам категории состояния по ошибке, за исключением слова накурено.

Как доказать? Можно посмотреть Большой толковый словарь русского языка на Грамоте.ру


СУМРАЧНО. I. нареч. к Сумрачный (3 зн.). С. смотреть. Кто-л. выглядит с. II. в функц. безл. сказ. 1. О наличии сумрака, полумрака где-л. В глухом лесу с. В подвале было с. 2. О наличии мрачного, тяжёлого настроения у кого-л. На душе было с.
НАКУРЕНО, нареч., в функц. сказ. (где). О наличии дыма от курения; о сильном запахе табачного дыма в помещении. Н. табаком, махоркой. Здесь очень н.!
Так у нас маркируются слова категории состояния.  А для решено, указано и т. д. ничего такого нет.

Почему не пишется СКС?
 Вопрос:  Правомерно ли выделять слова категории 
 состояния в самостоятельную часть речи? 
 Ответ: Лингвисты высказывают разные точки 
 зрения на этот вопрос. В академической «Русской 
 грамматике» такая часть речи не выделяется. 



Поэтому пока СКС — это так называемые слова категории состояния.
Но может на этом сайте все правильно, как вы думаете?

просто меня смутил тот факт, что «накурено» является кр.страдательным причастием…а остальные скс чаще всего схожи с наречиями

Мне понятен ваш вопрос, а СКС вообще одна из самых сложных тем в лингвистике.  Позже я попробую уделить больше внимания этой теме.


Правильно то, что правильным считают лингвисты…

А лингвисты считают так — РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК : ЭНЦИКЛОПЕДИЯ / Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова Рос. акад. наук; Гл. ред., [авт. предисл.] Ю. Н. Караулов. - 2-е изд., перераб. и доп. - Москва : Большая рос. энцикл. : Изд. дом "Дрофа", 1997:




Такая точка зрения на состав слов состояния присутствует в трудах В.В. Виноградова, Е.М. Галкиной-Федорук, И. Сапожникова, Л.А. Коробчинской…
Однако из-за того, что страдательные причастия вроде построено, вымыто  выражают не столько состояния, сколько результат действия, НЕ ВСЕ лингвисты причисляют их к словам состояния.
Ну а в разных учебниках у разных лингвистов точки зрения на состав слов состояния = слов категории состояния = предикативов = безлично-предикативных слов могут и не совпадать…

Толковый ответ со ссылкой на конкретный источник и правильная мысль о том, что в языке нет универсальных правил. Слава, плюсую. Призываю не вестись на вопросы про школы и словари. Их следует задать авторам школ и словарей

Из одного из ответов в этой теме:

Полагаю, что вопрос закономерен. Слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода, отнесены к словам категории состояния по ошибке, за исключением слова накурено.
Как доказать? Можно посмотреть Большой толковый словарь русского языка на Грамоте.ру

Думаю, что школьникам, которые воспользуются такой рекомендацией , не грозит победа на олимпиадах по русскому языку.
Слово НАТОПТАНО в словарях вряд ли найдётся, тем не менее на олимпиадах (видимо, и в каких-то школьных учебниках)  словом категории состояния оно всё же считается.
Нашёл в Сети:
















Из одного из ответов в этой теме:

Слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода, отнесены [на сайте https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/kategoriia-sostoianiia.html#i-3 ] к словам категории состояния по ошибке, за исключением слова накурено.

Нет, не по ошибке.
См. КРАТКУЮ РУССКУЮ ГРАММАТИКУ под ред. Н.Ю. Шведовой и В.В. Лопатина (М., 1989):


Иногда, да не всегда. Речь идет о модальных предикативах. Поэтому отрывайте словарь на Грамоте и проверяйте. В сказуемых там приказано, велено, положено.  Но нет решено, задумано, указано. У Кустовой все эти предикативы расписаны по группам: есть модальные и не модальные. В современной грамматике  все причастные предикативы не относятся к СКС. У Тихонова это хорошо объясняется: (1) значение действия, а не признака; (2) много грамматических несовпадений.  Надо знать   современную науку, а не  прошлый век.

Из дискуссии на форуме:
 Мне понятен ваш вопрос, а СКС вообще одна из самых 
 сложных тем в лингвистике. Позже я попробую 
 уделить больше внимания этой теме.

А это подробное раскрытие этой темы в отдельном ответе:
ПРИЧАСТНЫЕ ПРЕДИКАТИВЫ — ЭТО СЛОВА КАТЕГОРИИ СОСТОЯНИЯ (СКС) ИЛИ НЕТ?
Цитата из ответа:
В АГ-80 такие слова названы причастными предикативами.
Несмотря на совпадение тем этих групп слов, можно заметить и принципиальное различие: СКС имеют значение качественного (нединамического) признака, а предикативные причастия имеют значение признака по действию (процессуального признака).
Но вот участник форума @Слава высказывает сомнения и дает свой ответ, а также предлагает собственную трактовку информации из статьи "Предикативы". Из переписки по теме:
На самом деле в статье А.Б. Летучего, на которую 
ссылался автор ответа, говорится так: 
Морфологически предикативы могут быть сходны с 
прилагательными (а также ПРИЧАСТИЯМИ), наречиями 
или существительными.

А это мой ответ (о причастиях):
Я тогда в другой раз как-нибудь зайду и объясню 
вам, что такое "сходны морфологически". А вы пока 
подумайте, есть ли морфологическое сходство между 
причастиями и отглагольными прилагательными. 

ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ РАЗБОР
Важно отметить, что эта тема имеет ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ — как школьникам делать грамматический разбор таких слов. Думается, что решение здесь однозначное, а другие (свои) мнения в школе высказывать не рекомендуется. Грамматика — точная наука, и разные мнения могут иметь лингвисты. Но уже в учебниках для педвузов важно отразить устоявшееся во времени решение на текущий момент.
Часть речи слова решено — причастие, образовано от 
глагола решить.
Морфологические признаки
Начальная форма:
решённый (именительный падеж единственного числа 
мужского рода).
Постоянные признаки:
страдательное, прошедшее время, совершенный вид.
Непостоянные признаки:
единственное число, средний род, краткая форма.
Синтаксическая роль
В предложении причастие в краткой форме выступает в 
роли сказуемого (решено).

А как разбирать слова категории состояния? Грамота предлагает такое решение:
№ 214044
какая часть речи - "надо"
ответ
Это предикатив.

А это один из разборов в Сети слова можно:
1. Часть речи. Предикатив
2. Начальная форма – “можно”, не изменяется.
3. Синтаксическая роль
в функц. безл. сказ. с инф. 1. О возможности для 
осуществления чего-л.;  Сегодня м. кататься лыжах. 
2. кому-чему и с инф. Разрешается, позволительно. 
М. войти.  И др. по толковому словарю

О ТЕРМИНОЛОГИИ (для справок)

В общем случае ПРЕДИКАТИВЫ — это слова в роли предиката (сказуемого) в безличном предложении.

В этом значении к предикативам относятся:
предикативные наречия (значение признака)
предикативные причастия (значение действия).
слова нет, не было, хватит, достаточно и др.

Нет сомнений, что слова категории состояния должны обозначать именно СОСТОЯНИЕ (то есть признак), но никак не  действие. Точно так же мы различаем отглагольные прилагательные и причастия.

К  СКС ОТНОСЯТСЯ: слова, обозначающие состояние природы и человека (холодно, светло, больно, обидно, весело, интересно), восприятие (видно, слышно);  также они могут иметь модальные и оценочные значения (можно, нужно, стыдно, хорошо, тяжело), количественные значения (достаточно).

Предикативам посвящена отдельная статья в Русской корпусной грамматике, где ничего не говорится о причастных предикативах. Предикативы как отдельный класс введены в научный оборот Л. В. Щербой, которым назвал их «категорией состояния».


Предикативы
